# Can't add method, via Swift extension, to objective-c NSManagedObject Subclass

Tags: objective-c, swift

The code generator for NSManagedObject subclasses in Xcode 7.2- isn't on pair with the code generation for Objective-C. (No accessor methods for to-many relationships.)

So I want to do this:

- Generate NSManagedObject subclasses in Objective-C.
- Create a Bridging header file.
- Write Swift extensions for the generated Objective-C classes.
- Use the extended objective-C classes in Swift.

I do the steps above, but I get a **Value of type Person, has no member syHello** error, when I try to call the code below.

Objective-C:

```
@interface Person (CoreDataProperties)

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<Pet *> *pets;

@end

@interface Person (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addPetsObject:(Pet *)value;
- (void)removePetsObject:(Pet *)value;
- (void)addPets:(NSSet<Pet *> *)values;
- (void)removePets:(NSSet<Pet *> *)values;

@end
```

Swift:

```
public extension Person {

    public func sayHello() {

        print("Hello! My name is \(self.name).")

    }

}
```

Swift:

```
let myPerson = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: myAppDelegate.managedObjectContext) as! Person
myPerson.sayHello()
```

What do I need to do for the compiler to pick upp my extension on my Person class, so that I can call sayHello on it?

Comment: That should work. Do you import both "Person.h" and "Pet.h" in the bridging header file?

Comment: Yes! This is the content of my bridging header file.

#import "Person+CoreDataProperties.h"
#import "Person.h"

#import "Pet+CoreDataProperties.h"
#import "Pet.h"

Comment: Is the "Target Membership" checkbox selected for the Swift file with the extension?

Comment: If I check under Target Membership in the file inspector, the checkbox for my target is not checked. But I can't check it either. What must I do to be able to check it?

Comment: That is strange. How did you add the file to the project? What is the file name?

Comment: I used Xcode New Swift file. The name is ManagedObjectExtensions.swift

Comment: There is something strange and I cannot reproduce the problem. If you add a new Swift file to the project then the target membership should already be  on. Perhaps try it with a new Swift file.

Comment: Tried a new file, the target was added, and now it works! Strange! But thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As Martin R pointed out; my Swift file was not connected to my target. Replaced my Swift file with a new one, and it worked.